# Setting Zoom on Windows Mobile device with IAMCameraControl::Set()

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, directshow, zooming, video-capture

I am developing an application for video capture and I would like to implement zoom functionality.

Working with DirectShow I came across IAMCameraControlInterface. It has a method ::Set(), which should be used for setting several camera parameters.

However I played around and I couldn't do anything with it. Then I tried to call ::GetRange() method which should return the range of possible parameter values but it didn't return anything.

Is it really possible that the device doesn't support any option? It seems very strange because the native camera application supports zoom, but I really don't know where could be the main problem for such strange results.

Has anyone any experience with similar applications? Does anyone know what could be wrong here or how to effectively use [IAMCameraControlInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa929836.aspx) functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any personal experience, but have a look at this [forum port](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/b74ac0ab-edc9-4a9c-959c-d42d9f40884c/). According to a replier, the driver may not implement the IAMCameraControl interface correctly and rely on implementation specific tricks to do zoom in and out.

As far as I know (please someone correct or verify it) the camera driver isn't part of the Windows Mobile certification process. This means that the manufacturer can do as he pleases with it.